# Copying stdout and stdin to ssh tunnel, not working with fmt.Print

Tags: go

I'm using a ssh tunnel from my PC, A, to remote embedded system, B. I want to start a process on B with a string from the terminal in A.

This is my PC code in essense

```
sshOut, err := session.StdoutPipe()
sshIn, err := session.StdinPipe()

go io.Copy(os.Stdout, sshOut)
go io.Copy(sshIn, os.Stdin) 

fmt.Print("Start")
```

Code on embedded system in essense

```
var str string
fmt.Print("Im embedded")
fmt.Scan(&str)
if str == "Start"{
     startProcess()
}
```

So, when I run the program on my pc I get "Im embedded" in the terminal, so the ssh pipe is working. The process on the embedded system starts if I write "Start" in the terminal, but not by fmt.Print("Start").

*Is there a difference between fmt.Print and to write in terminal? Isn't both os.Stdout?*

Comment: If you use `fmt.Println("Start")` or `fmt.Print("Start\n")`, does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

fmt.Fprint(os.Stdin, "Start") does not work, but fmt.Fprint(sshIn, "Start") seems to work.